# running jsp file with tomcat 6

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I created `dynamic web project` , and add 2 items :

1. `index.jsp` page like this :

   ```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
       pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
           <form action="GrettingServlet" method="POST">
           First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" size="20"><br>
           Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
           <br><br>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form> 

   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. in *default package* `servlet` like this (called `GrettingServlet.java`):

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;

   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   public class GrettingServlet extends HttpServlet {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       public GrettingServlet() {
           super();
       }

       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }

       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
           response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
           String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName").toString();
           String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName").toString();

           out.println("<html>");
           out.println("<head>");
           out.println("<title>Servlet GreetingServlet</title>");
           out.println("</head>");
           out.println("<body>");
           out.println("<p>Welcome " + firstName + " " + lastName + "</p>");
           out.println("</body>");
           out.println("</html>");

           out.close();
       }

   }
   ```

I installed `tomcat6` so that I have `Apache Software Foundation` folder  . 
finally I want to create `war` file of this project, so I chose on the project `Export>War file` and in the `Destination` text I chose the `webapps` folder in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps` . 
the project called `MyFirstServlet` . and in order to see the form of `index.jsp` on the server i write in the browser `http://localhost:8080/MyFirstServlet/` but I get the message

```
HTTP Status 404 - /MyFirstServlet/

type Status report

message /MyFirstServlet/

description The requested resource (/MyFirstServlet/) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

the servlet mapping is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyFirstServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>new</description>
    <display-name>GrettingServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>GrettingServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GrettingServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I checked the tomcat and it on `service status : started`

What can be the problem ?

Comment: please show your servlet mapping in the web.xml

Comment: @MaVRoSCy added to the follow message  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given example, you are expected to deploy your web application into your Tomcat as MyFirstServlet.war (or as an exploded directory - this makes no difference) and have your GrettingServlet mapped to the *application root* - if you want the servlet to handle the root:

Your `/WEB-INF/web.xml` should have these so:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.package.GrettingServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Note the typo:** "Gretting" (in servlet and mappings) vs "Greeting" (in JSP form)

With your setup you should be pointing your browser at `http://localhost:8080/MyFirstServlet/GrettingServlet` to reach the servlet.

If your idea is to have JSP page to handle the root, then you should browse to either `http://localhost:8080/MyFirstServlet/<yourJSPName>.jsp` or have the JSP called `index.jsp` or `default.jsp` (see `<welcome-file-list/>` section of your `web.xml`). In this case your idea, I guess, is to display a JSP and then post to the servlet, therefore make sure your servlet specification and mapping is correct (`web.xml` servlet mapping and the JSP form `action` attribute).

Comment: my idea is to see the html form of 'index.jsp'   . when i change the 'web.xml' like you suggest it gave same error .

Comment: In this case it looks like your web app isn't getting deployed. Can you check Tomcat's logs?

Comment: a have folder 'logs' in 'Apache Software Foundation' what i have to check there ? when i write ' http://localhost:8080' i see the Tomcat welcome page .

Comment: I'd look through the error.log to see any mentions of your MyFirstServlet application. One other thing maybe worth checking is if you have a Tomcat manager application installed, you could check your app status there: `http://localhost:8080/manager`

Comment: i finally remove and reinstall the tomcat and it fixed .

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your web.xml with the following and it should work

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>GrettingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/GreetingServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**UPDATE**  HERE IS THE WHOLE WEB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyFirstServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>new</description>
    <display-name>GrettingServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>GrettingServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GrettingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GreetingServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: i changed in the servlet and servlet mapping tag like you write but still i get same message  .

Comment: i am running your code with that change only to the web.xml and it works fine

Comment: can you please write all the web.xml again and what write in the browser  ? you see the the 2 text and the button when you run it ?

Comment: in the browser it writes      Welcome <textbox1> <textbox2>